# Divinity 2 blessing the blood in bowl in the puzzle in Lucian's Tomb

Tags: divinity-original-sin-2

I am completely stuck and at this point I am not sure if this is a bug or my IQ is lacking (sadly chances are it's the latter)...

> I have managed to solve the pipe part of the puzzle and also figured out that I need to cast rain blood in to the central hole... however when I bless the blood it gets blessed up to the bowl so it does not work...

[image]

**Am I missing something obvious here how do I bless the blood 'all the way'?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this one out myself... or maybe bug hacked the game... I will let you decide...

The trick is to throw through the field one of pyramids and then teleport to it  with your party, then you can use teleport spell to teleport char that has bless spell and some source down where the puzzle blocks and bowl is and bless the bowl with blood at point blank...

Hope this saves you some time.